# Visual studio 2013 web express missing toolbox icons

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webforms

My toolbox icons seem to be missing, in addition it shows the "pointer" on every freaking category. It happened when I was trying to add a new category for my obout controls, however I used the 3.5 and 2.0 version and perhaps it caused some conflict. I reset the toolbar but the screenshot is what came up.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the command prompt:

```
  devenv /resetskippkgs
```

It restored my toolbox settings! They were all gone before that.